# Can I get event.target when there are nested jQuery calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-events

I am trying to find the event DOM target when there are nested jQuery calls. If there was only one level of call, then event.target would get the DOM target and I could go from there.  But how to get through nested calls?

I am testing with a Javascript function

```
jQuery(document).bind('gform_post_render', function(event, formID){
    jQuery("#id").val(event.target.nodeName);
});
```

I can look at event.target.nodeName and see that it is "#document".  I assume that is because the trigger which called this function was something like

```
jQuery(document).trigger('gform_post_render', ...);
```

And I think there is another level or two of calls above that.
What I'd like to be able to do is something like

```
event.trigger.event.trigger.closest(.classname).attr("attname");
```

although I realize that 'event.target.event.target' is not allowed.

Is there any way to do this?

BTW, what I am trying to do is extract a piece of data from the HTML that is going though a couple of WordPress plugins (popup and gravity forms) that do the jQuery calls. So I have no ability to change things, just trying to deal with what they did.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a data argument to `trigger`, and then access it within the handler. So you pass it like this:

```
$(document).trigger('gform_post_render', {target: event.target});
```

and then in the handler:

```
$(document).on('gform_post_render', function(event, data) {
    var target = data.target;
    ...
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change the trigger calls - that is in the javascript created by the plugin's, and I don't think its even possible to override it all.

Comment: Then I think you're screwded. Events aren't linked to each other automatically just because you trigger one event in the handler for another.